# How to delete multiple first columns from multiple files?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have multiple files like this:

```
trans_ENSG00000047849.txt.traw
trans_ENSG00000047848.txt.traw
trans_ENSG00000047847.txt.traw
...
```

and each has around 300 columns. Columns are separated with tab.I would like to remove the first 7 columns from each of those files.

I know how to do it for each file:

```
cut  -f 7- trans_ENSG00000047849.txt.traw > trans_ENSG00000047849.txt.trawN
```

Is there is a way to do it at once for all files?

NOTE: there is a tab at the beginning. Therefore I used here cut -f 7 rather than cut -f 8 to remove the first 7 columns.

Comment: `cut -f 7-` means to remove **6** columns. Since you have a `tab` at every beginning, so I guess you want to remove `5` columns of real data ;)

Comment: I want to remove 7 columns. I do have tab at the beginning so because of that I am doing cut  -f 7.

Comment: Ah... that's strange.  Anyway, so long the problem is solved, I guess we can just ignore this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Backup your files first**, and try this (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri 's/^([^\t]*\t){7}//' trans_*.txt.traw
```

As `-i` to sed will change your files in place. (You can remove the `i` for testing).

Eg:

```
$ cat file
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
a       b       c       d       e       f       g       h       i       j

        dfad            da
$ sed -ri 's/^([^\t]*\t){7}//' file

$ cat file
8       9       0
h       i       j

        dfad            da
```

However, the command's for simple, so it won't remove when there're less than 7 columns. (Guess you won't have lines like this, right?)

If you still want to remove when there're less than 7 columns:

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]*(\t|$)){,7}//'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. this removes first 8 columns, should I rather do: sed -ri 's/^([^\t]*\t){6}//' trans_*.txt.traw

Comment: @anikaM  Put some sample data in your question. The command should only remove seven columns( seven columns and their `TAB` after).

Comment: yes it has tab at the beginning, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `for` loop:

```
for file in *.txt.traw
do 
    cut  -f 7- "$file" > "$file"N
done
```